# How can I detect that Skype For Business Click to Call is enabled in IE11 compatibility mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, skype-for-business

Something about Skype for Business' "Click to Call" grinds my web application to a halt. I have to kill the browser to get out. When I disable Click to Call everything works perfectly.

I've tried using `navigator.plugins` to detect Click to Call, but it always returns 0 plugins. I've tried the `try{ new ActiveXObject('Skype.Detection') }` method but that always comes back with `Automation Server can't create object`.

I've tried looking for spans with `skype_tb` in the id, but it doesn't seem to find anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get around the Click to Call problem.

I added my work phone number to the page, then check for the Click to Call added anchor tag in the div. If it's there, I know the plugin is enabled, so I display an alert and instructions on disabling it.

Works for me.